# How do I remove objects?

Tags: timber-and-stone

How do I remove objects after building them, for example a fence that I placed without taking into account its orientation? I have right clicked on it like you would a structure but nothing happened. I have also tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+`Click` and nothing has happened. I couldn't think of any other solutions as this is my first game.

Comment: What kind of structure? like a door or a block?

Comment: @jacen.garriss structure as in anything under the structure tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For structures you can just right click and dismantle, but for actual blocks (like fences) you need to highlight the area for dig/mining. This will require a miner with a pickaxe (regardless of what you're removing) to actually remove the material.